# Tab Slider Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms cross-platform (PCL) and would like to add tabs, there would be two "Users" and "Hashtags" when the page opens default is "Users" you can switch between tabs by clicking the tab on the top or slide to it.

My problem is I do not know what it is called and what to research, I tried looking for tab page but it shows Tabbed Layouts in the action bar (For Android only) I also don't want it to take up the whole page since I would like to add a search bar (Entry) above it.

An example of what I am trying to figure out how to do it in the image below from instagram

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you are showing there is not really a default view on iOS.

However, these types of views are usually called Tab Pager, Tab Indicator on Android it is called Tab Layout.

I have ported over SGTabbedPager for iOS which can be found here: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/SGTabbedPager

You could create a custom renderer for Xamarin.Forms which uses this internally or some other library you find suitable.